# How to reference the WCF service by code-behind in UWP?

Tags: wcf, uwp

Now I need to reference a WCF service in a UWP program. However, the address of the WCF service may change frequently in the future.

I don't want to rebuild/republish the project every time when the address change.

So I want to use a `LocalSettings` to Save/Load the address of WCF service. Every the program begins, it will reload the address from the `LocalSettings`. And if the address changes, I just only let the customer change the `LocalSettings` from UI but not need to rebuild/republish the project.

How can I do it? Or there is any other better to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a [RESTful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) service, you could use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) relevant APIs to consume a REST service in UWP.

Please note that REST is a resource that implements a uniform interface using standard HTTP GET, POST, PUT methods that can be located by URI. So, you could use HttpClient to call it in code-behind. You will get response after you send http request, then you could analysis the response result.

The similar thread for your reference: [Calling web service asynchronously in page constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066196/calling-web-service-asynchronously-in-page-constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Using `LocalSettings` for such thing is a good solution.

`LocalSettings` are just a dictionary where you can assign values you want to store and later take out.

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings["ServiceAddress"] = "something";
Debug.WriteLine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings["ServiceAddress"]);
```

Such setting will survive app restart and is stored in applicaton's private storage.

You will probably want to seed this setting with a default value at first startup.

Comment: I am sorry about that I had known how to use the LocalSettings,  but now I don't know how to reference the address in code-behind for the address is a variable. Maybe you had misunderstood my meaning yet.